# Spring Initializr creating invalid project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-initializr

I am trying to create a Spring Boot app via Spring Initializr with the following settings

Kotlin
Gradle
Dependencies - Web

The project that it downloads has a few issues when imported in to IntelliJ

When trying to build it has the error
Error:Invalid keystore format
Gradle project refresh failed

Also when i try and add a Kotlin class new class isn't available but I believe this to be because the project hasn't properly refreshed yet

Comment: Can you run that same project on the command line? What version of IJ are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ Community edition, latest version

Comment: there's no support of initializer in the community edition. You didn't answer my first question.

Comment: I didn't try from the command line, I want to get this working from with IntelliJ anyway.
So if I have the full version of IntelliJ will the outcome be any different when I try and load the generated files?